# Mapping of drug names to generics

Tags: openfda

Dataset: Obtained from FDA AERS

I would like to map the drug names to its generic name.

Example: Arthritis Pain, Aspir 81, Aspir-Low, Bayer Childrens Aspirin etc
would be mapped to aspirin

Is there a dataset where such mappings are available(preferably in CSV format) so that it is possible to iterate through the FDA AERS dataset and replace the drug name with their generics.

Comment: [Here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/14027/how-to-get-all-generic-names-in-the-api-drug-label) are all the generic names to start with. I don't know OpenFDA, but maybe you can go from there in the other direction, i.e. querying for brand names associated with generic names.

Comment: Or try going from [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3934/why-does-a-report-listing-a-generic-drug-drospirenone-and-ethinyl-estradiol-ha). BTW Did you [search the site](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=drug+names) before posting your question?

Comment: @JanDoggen Yes,  I went through them, but I wanted to know if someone in the community knew of the availability of such database.

Answer (score 0):

We at openFDA are unaware of such dataset, but you could probably compile such mappings by a) downloading openFDA FAERS JSON files, b) writing a quick tool that goes over the records and puts the mappings together.